# How to List certain amount at the time when running a command that returns lots of lines?

Tags: server

I'm using UBuntu Server cmd only. When I run something, `apt list --installed` for example, that returns more records than the available area (not using putty) it shows only the bottom results.

Is there a way it limits the records at a given time and when I press a key it moves to the next wave of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the result through a pager such as `less` or `more`:

```
apt list --installed | less
```

Page through using <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and quit with <kbd>Q</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It's already mentioned as an aside in steel's answer but I think many would be comfortable with using `more` instead of `less`. It's an old DOS (Disk Operating System) command which may have been lifted from Unix in the first place:

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | more
```

After filling the screen with the first 24 lines or so, `more` allows you to press:

- <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the next line to be displayed.
- <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> for the next 24 lines (or so) to be displayed.
- <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

On second thought perhaps both DOS and Unix lifted the `more` pipe from CP/M *shrugs*.